# Failure to trigger alarm for custom HeartBeat metric in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

There are set of machine hosted in on premise network in my company.
There's one windows service, lets say ServiceX, is running on each of these host.
These ServiceX after each interval polls database.
Before polling the database, I have added following line to emit a metric

TelemetryClient().GetMetric("AgentHeartBeat").TrackValue(1)

So, every time the ServiceX polls, I can see a heart beat custom metric in Azure Application Insights.

Now to setup the alarm I am using following query,

```
customMetrics
| where name == 'AgentHeartBeat'
| summarize AggregatedValue =  avg(valueMin) by bin(timestamp, 1min),
   cloud_RoleInstance
```

> Note, cloud_RoleInstance value = Environment.MachineName

Please check below figure for complete Alarm configuration.

[image: Alarm configuration]

---

To test the alarm I turned of one of machine (hosting ServiceX), but this alarm still not triggered.
I am not sure what exactly I need to change to make it working.

Comment: The screenshot is broken:(.

Comment: please check now

Comment: still cannot see it. Please follow [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498) to add screenshot in your question:).